# Scraping map data with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from this  [link](https://maps.sygic.com/#/?map=8,40.463632,16.171875):

I checked many posts regarding google maps but I can't find for this one...

I need to **scrape** the data for all the data point (pictures in a circle).
[image]

When we click on a picture then all the data then getting all the data... I can **scrape** the data for this but don't know how to locate the circle in "inspect"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to parse data via site's API.

You can get all information about POI by it's id:

```
https://api-cdn.sygictraveldata.com/v2.6/en/places/poi:{id}
```

Ids can be easy obtained from URL.

If you have list of points you need to crawl - it is easy to do. If you need to get this list - this task is much more complicated. Geos on this site (and it is usual practice) have parents and children (so one POI can have another POI as a child).